# Dynamically built predicate is not working as expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework, predicate

One of my functions searching for elements in EF-based db using predicate to define query. It uses `param int[] paymentsIds` because it can used variable number of parameters. So I had to construct predicate dynamically. I have 2 codes: one static (code 2)  and second "almost dynamic with static parameters (code 1)". For me they should  both works, but only static code works (code 2). Why is the dynamically constructed predicate not working?

Code of method with marks where code 1 & code 2 starts and ends:

```
public IEnumerable<MwbePayment> FindPaymentByIds(int userId, params int[] ids)
    {
        //code 1 starts
        ids = new int[] { 53, 54, 55 };
        //prepare predicate dynamically
        Expression<Func<MwbePayment, bool>> innerPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<MwbePayment>();
        foreach (int id in ids)
        {
            int tempInt = id;
            innerPredicate = innerPredicate.Or(x => x.Id == tempInt);
        }

        Expression<Func<MwbePayment, bool>> outerPredicate = PredicateBuilder.And(innerPredicate, x => x.UserData.Id == userId);

        Debug.WriteLine("outerPredicate body = {0}", outerPredicate );
        IQueryable<MwbePayment> query = DbSet.AsNoTracking().Where(outerPredicate );

        //code 1 ends

        /*
        //code 2 starts
        Expression<Func<MwbePayment, bool>> innerPredicate2 = x => (x.Id == 53 || x.Id == 54 || x.Id == 55) && x.User.Id == userId;
        Debug.WriteLine("innerPredicate2 body = {0}", innerPredicate2);
        IQueryable<MwbePayment> query = DbSet.AsNoTracking().Where(innerPredicate2);
        //code 2 ends
        */

        return query.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

Predicate for code 1 printed to Debug.Writeline:

```
f => (((False OrElse Invoke(x => (x.Id == value(MobileWallet.DAL.MwbePaymentRepository+<>c__DisplayClassc).tempInt), f)) OrElse Invoke(x => (x.Id == value(MobileWallet.DAL.MwbePaymentRepository+<>c__DisplayClassc).tempInt), f)) OrElse Invoke(x => (x.Id == value(MobileWallet.DAL.MwbePaymentRepository+<>c__DisplayClassc).tempInt), f))
```

Predicate for code 2 printed to Debug.Writeline:

x => (((x.Id == 53) OrElse (x.Id == 54)) OrElse (x.Id == 55))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to resort to complex predicate builders, this query boils down to a fairly simple query:

```
return DbSet.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id) && x.UserData.Id == userId);
```

However to answer your question, you have a small typo in your code. The line with the `Where` clause is using `innerPredicate` instead of `outerPredicate` so it should be:

```
IQueryable<MwbePayment> query = DbSet.AsNoTracking().Where(outerPredicate);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, it looks good but still wondering what is wrong with my idea.

Comment: Well the first one should be using `outerPredicate` in the `Where` right?

Comment: Condition with Userid.id is not needed because it caused that both predicate are not equal. It was my fault in code;)

Comment: Anyway :), I rolled back my update to not mess in example;). Thanks for answer it works:)